# Need help in understanding Pointers and Strings using stack and heap memory

Tags: pointers, memory-management, c-strings

I was trying to understand underlying process when pointers, strings and functions are combined along with heap/stack memory. I was able to understand and learn, but I ended up with two errors which I failed to find out why.

My problem lies here:

```
// printf("%s\n", *ptrToString); // Gives bad mem access error if heap memory used
// printf("%s\n", ptrToString);  // Output is wrong if stack was used for memory, and prints some hex values instead
```

Can anyone explain what am I missing here ? Also, I would like to ask some feedback about my code, and suggest any improvements we can make.

Thanks

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USE_STACK_MEMORY 0

char* NewString(char string[])
{
    unsigned long num_chars;
    char *copy = NULL;

    // Find string length
    num_chars = strlen(string);

    // Allocate memory
#if USE_STACK_MEMORY
    copy = alloca(sizeof(copy) + num_chars + 1); // Use stack memory
#else
    copy = malloc(sizeof(copy) + num_chars + 1);    // Use heap memory
#endif

    // Make a local copy
    strcpy(copy, string);

    // If we use stack then it returns a string literal
    return copy;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ptrToString = NULL;

    ptrToString = NewString("HI");

    printf("%s\n", ptrToString);

    // printf("%s\n", *ptrToString); // Gives bad mem access error if heap memory used
    // printf("%s\n", ptrToString);  // Output is wrong if stack was used for memory, and prints some hex values instead

#if !USE_STACK_MEMORY
    if ( ptrToString ) {
        free(ptrToString);
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first print reads the value where the pointer points to. It interprets this value then as a pointer to a string. This means the first value of your string will be interpreted as the address where the string would be. 
The second print is wrong for stack memory because the memory you allocate with `alloca` is automatically freed as soon as your NewString method returns.

From the man page of alloca:

> The alloca() function allocates size bytes of space in the stack frame
>   of the caller. This temporary space is automatically freed when the
>   function that called alloca() returns to its caller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood about alloca, but if I try to debug I can see that function returns "HI" value which is copied successfully to ptrToString. Then If try to print its value and I get some hex value.

Comment: Your memory error is thrown, because the first print interprets the first value of your string as an address, which will most probably be invalid. If your pointer points to the string `"HelloWorld"` (in hex `0x48656c6c6f576f726c64`), then in the first print the function will try to read a string from the address `0x48656c6c`, which will most probably be invalid or your program is not allowed to access it.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: It is not guaranteed that if you access already freed memory your old values are still there. This is just undefined behaviour.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. PS: I keep forgetting about undefined behavior thing.

Comment: @Sebestial Walla, Any suggestions to improve my code ? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I guess it's not simply printing a string..

Comment: @Sebestian Walla, well like I said in my first post, I am just trying to learn and understand how they work internally. I am requesting you share feedback on quality of code or any optimizations. Thanks

Comment: Well returning values on the stack is bad practice, which can even be lead to security vulnerabilities. If your created string would be user supplied you would have a buffer overflow vulnerability, as you don't check the amount of allocated bytes for integer overflow.  So you need to check that.

Comment: The asterisk is a dereference operator meaning it gives you the value, which is saved in a pointer so the address where it points to. The & would give you the address of the variable.

Comment: I guess you should just research about those operators.